# Transform a string to another string using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

In order to work in a functional programming way, I want to transform a string without having to use a temporary variable. I would like to do that only using pure JS or lodash.

Given (as asked by @nina-scholz):

```
const input = 'a string from somewhere';
const option1 = true;
const option2 = false;
const applyOption1 = str => 'prefix-' + str;
const applyOption2 = str => str + '-suffix';
const myFilter = str => str.contains('somewhere');
```

What I have:

```
let cleanedInput = input;
if (option1) {
  cleanedInput = applyOption1(cleanedInput);
}
if (option2) {
  cleanedInput = applyOption2(cleanedInput);
}

return _.chain(cleanedInput)
  .split('')
  .filter(blabla)
  .value();
```

What I want:

```
return _.chain(input)
  .SOMETHING(value => (option1 ? applyOption1(value) : value))
  .SOMETHING(value => (option2 ? applyOption2(value) : value))
  .split('')
  .filter(blabla)
  .value();
```

I would foolishly use `map` but it iterates over chars of the string. So what can I use for SOMETHING ?

Thanks!

Comment: please add the content of `blabla`, `option1`, etc and the functions like `applyOption1`. and some input and wanted output as well.

Comment: Have a look at [thru](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#thru).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @gruff-bunny, the method I was searching for is [thru](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#thru)

Another solution I found was to put my string in an array, then do a `head()` after all my `map` calls.